# Alternatives to send php header information to the Ajax Requests

Tags: php, ajax, json, authentication, header

I have a login script on my website where in what I am doing is

1) Creating a Login form

2) Using Ajax to post requests when user submits login form

3) This Ajax request passes the data to a file called ajaxhandler.php ( It has a calls to various apis like signup, contact, login ) and expects a json reply its contents are displayed at the bottom.

4) Ajaxhandler.php calls various functions depending on api and they return json data to ajaxhandler.php which writes it to the ajax request.

5) Now I want to redirect the user on successful login. But ajax request expects json data and if I send the php header location Information the ajax request's location is redirected ( which I found after some googling ). I don't want to change the entire frameworks my seniors set up so what should I do ( One solution I found on google was to use document.location or window.location , But that would expose my secure location of website to the world and won't be secure ) So how do I do this?

AjaxHandler Code -

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['apiName']) && $_REQUEST['apiName'] != null) {
    $apiName = $_REQUEST['apiName'];
    switch ($apiName) {
        case 'requestSignUp':
            echo UberHealth::requestSignUp($_REQUEST['email']);
            break;
        case 'login':
            echo UberHealth::contact($_REQUEST['email'], $_REQUEST['password']);
            break;
        default:
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 404, 'reason' => 'Invalid api called'));
            break;
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 404, 'reason' => 'Parameters missing. Invalid request!'));
}
```

Uberhealth Class code - >

```
class UberHealth
{

    public static function login($email,$password){
      // login checking code using redbeanphp which returns json status code and message but I want to send the header location information from here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect to another page base on the returned JSON values without refreshing the page?

Comment: Yes... I meant that but i cant use php headers it seems

Comment: I think in that case you need to return a redirect page with all headers by php instead of the JSON. I mean in php side you check if the login was successful return a redirect page and in the javascript just present the redirected page